# How do make the error message more informative in chef resource execute?

Tags: chef-infra

Here is some chef code that is trying to untar a file into some directory.

The recipe is called from deep within some other recipes and it fails **randomly**.

```
unless ::File.exists?(::File.join(node[:zookeeper][:install_dir], zk_basename))

  execute 'install zookeeper' do  # <-- Line 57
    user node[:zookeeper][:user]
    cwd Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]
    command "tar -C #{node[:zookeeper][:install_dir]} -zxf #{zk_basename}.tar.gz"
  end
end
```

The error I see is:

```
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[install zookeeper] (zookeeper::add line 57) had an error:
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2' . ,
FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[install zookeeper] (zookeeper::add line 57) had an error:
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '2' .
```

Since the error happens randomly in an environment I dont have ssh access to, I want to improve the chef recipe to catch this error and provide more details in the error message like:

1. Size and created-date of the tar.gz file
2. Permissions of the target directory

Note that I have to put those in the error message of the exception only as that is the only thing that is visible (without ssh access) of a complicated chef run.

Answer (score 0):

You could add something like this

```
log 'log_important_bits' do
  message lazy {
    the_dir = ::File.stat(node[:zookeeper][:install_dir])
    the_file = ::File.stat(::File.join(node[:zookeeper][:install_dir], zk_basename))
    "file.size = #{the_file.size} ... put whatever you want here"
  }
  level :error # So you'll always see it
end
```